# Adding attachment to Gmail draft with Google Apps Script and Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I try to automatically attach a file from my Google Drive (so ideally with the file id) in my Gmail draft created with Google Apps Script and GMail API. I use the syntax below. Can I do that easily? Creating the draft works great by the way.

Thanks! Chris

```
  function createDraft() {

  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

  var htmlBody = 'Howzit';

  var raw = 
      'Subject: Howzit\n' + 
      'To: aa@bb.cc\n' +
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
      '\r\n' + htmlBody;

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8).replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');

  var params = {method:"post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                  "message": {
                    "raw": draftBody
                  }
                })
               };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about following sample script? This is a very simple script for attaching a file to a draft. So please modify this to your environment.

In order to use this script, please enable Gmail API at [API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard). And please import file ID to `fileId` in the script.

#### Sample script :

```
function createDraft() {
  var fileId = "### file id ###";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
  var htmlBody = 'Howzit';
  var raw = 
      'Subject: Howzit\r\n' + 
      'To: aa@bb.cc\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=##########\r\n\r\n' +
      '--##########\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' + htmlBody + '\r\n' +
      '--##########\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: ' + file.getMimeType() + '; charset=UTF-8; name="' + file.getName() + '"\r\n' +
      'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' + file.getName() + '"\r\n' +
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' + Utilities.base64Encode(file.getBlob().getBytes()) +
      '\r\n--##########\r\n';
  var draftBody = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(raw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var params = {
    method:"post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({"message": {"raw": draftBody}})
  };
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);
  Logger.log(resp)
}
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "id": "#####",
  "message": {
    "id": "#####",
    "threadId": "#####",
    "labelIds": [
      "DRAFT"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Image :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as a beast, wasn't able to find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Rutte Welcome. Thank you, too.

Comment: Quick extra question, what if I want to add two files to the e-mail? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Chris Rutte Please loop the part which attaches a file by separating using '--##########\r\n'.

Comment: Thanks, will try it this afternoon or tonight!

Comment: @Chris Rutte Welcome.

Comment: @Tanaike: I have an issue that might be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059883/how-to-add-media-upload-for-bigquery-rest-api-using-urlfetchapp. Can you please check it? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Hoang Trinh Thank you for your comment. I will check it.