# How to add media upload for BigQuery Rest API using UrlFetchApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-apps-script-addon

I need to stream data into BigQuery from my Google Apps Script addon.

But I need to use my service account only (I need to insert data into **my** BigQuery table, not user's BigQuery table)

I followed this example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data

Because Apps Script Advanced Service doesn't support service account natively, so I need to change this example a bit:

Instead of using Advanced Service BigQuery, I need to get the OAuth token from my service account, then using BigQuery Rest API to handle the same job:

This is what I did:

```
function getBigQueryService() {
  return (
    OAuth2.createService('BigQuery')
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Caching
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())

      // Locking
      .setLock(LockService.getUserLock())

      // Set the scopes.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
  )
}

export const insertLog = (userId, type) => {
  const bigQueryService = getBigQueryService()
  if (!bigQueryService.hasAccess()) {
    console.error(bigQueryService.getLastError())
    return
  }

  const projectId = bigqueryCredentials.project_id
  const datasetId = 'usage'
  const tableId = 'logs'
  const row = {
    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    userId,
    type,
  }

  const data = Utilities.newBlob(convertToNDJson(row), 'application/octet-stream')

  // Create the data upload job.
  const job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId,
          datasetId,
          tableId,
        },
        sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
      },
    },
  }

  const url = `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/${projectId}/jobs`
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${bigQueryService.getAccessToken()}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(job),
  }

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
    const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I get the Blob data (which is the actual json data that I need to put in BigQuery table) using this line:

```
const data = Utilities.newBlob(convertToNDJson(row), 'application/octet-stream')
```

But I don't know where to use this `data` with the BigQuery Rest API

The documentation doesn't mention it: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert

How this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: You need to send file and the job config as ['multipart/related'](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#multipart) data. See related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310991/).  Advanced Google services used to handle it for you. Now, you need to do this on your own

Comment: As an additional information for @TheMaster 's comment, how about using [this GAS library](https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp)? This library creates and requests the type of `multipart/form-data` using Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Tanaike: I see that what TheMaster mentioned was your code. Is there any documentation about those "\r\n" and "--". It's hard to understand that convention just by reading code. Also, thanks for your library, I think I will use it later if the manual way doesn't work.

Comment: @TheMaster: for the job.insert API, which parameters are corresponding to the "job" and "data"? The documentation is quite unclear for me

Comment: @Tanaike: your library FetchApp is neat. It solved the problem now and I will post it as the answer. But please give me an explanation about the manual way. I will also update the manual way in the answer when I understand it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the documents for multipart/form-data, how about [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)? I created the GAS library from these documents. The library creates the request body for multipart/form-data by inputting parameters and request it. So I cannot understand about `the manual way`. If you want to get the request body, for example, how about checking the library under the debug mode of the script editor?

Comment: @Tanaike: thank you. I mean `the manual way` is just how you built the string with those `\r\n` and `--`. But I think the link you provided is what I need to understand it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Also look into [rfc2387](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2387) and [rfc7578](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578). Despite bad font, it's actually easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can solve this problem using Tanaike's FetchApp library:

https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp#fetch

Anyone has this issue in the future: please check my comment in code to understand what was done.

Turn out, the `job` variable is treated as `metadata`, and the `data` variable is treated as `file` in the form data object

```
// First you need to convert the JSON to Newline Delimited JSON,
// then turn the whole thing to Blob using Utilities.newBlob

const data = Utilities.newBlob(convertToNDJson(row), 'application/octet-stream')

  // Create the data upload job.
  const job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        destinationTable: {
          projectId,
          datasetId,
          tableId,
        },
        sourceFormat: 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
      },
    },
  }

  const url = `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/${projectId}/jobs?uploadType=multipart`
  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${bigQueryService.getAccessToken()}`,
  }

  const form = FetchApp.createFormData() // Create form data
  form.append('metadata', Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(job), 'application/json'))
  form.append('file', data)

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers,
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    body: form,
  }

  try {
    FetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
```

Note: When you create the service account, choose role `BigQuery Admin`, or any role that has permission `bigquery.jobs.create`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery-roles

Because if you don't, you will have the error

> User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission...